# Automatic schema validation in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-11

Is there a way to automatically validate an XML document against a schema stored in the schema database? By automatic, I mean that if try to insert an invalid XML document (as per schema) using the `xdmp:document-insert()` function, it should not allow it and throw a relevant error.

I tried it, but even if the XML document doesn't match the schema, it is inserted without any errors. If I validate the same XML using the `xdmp:validate()` function, it shows errors as expected.

Note: I have added `targetNamespace` attribute to the schema document, and used the same namespace in the XML document.

Answer (score 1):

You Cannot force MarkLogic to validate during `xdmp:document-insert()` via an option on the function.

I see two choices for You:

1. Make Your own function that first validates and then calls document-insert
2. Validate as part of a pre-commit trigger.  If you make this code in a way that throws an error on validation failure, then the transaction is rolled back (for all docs in the transaction).  This is because the pre-commit trigger runs in the same transaction and context as the document being inserted.  See here: [Pre-Commit Trigger](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/triggers#id_34175)